# PDFMOutlookAddin.dll not compatible with Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-office-2016

Adobe has informed me that the reason I can no longer print PDF Portfolios from email is that they have not yet patched their PDF plug-in (PDFMOutlookAddin.dll) to work with Outlook 2016, despite the fact that Office 2016 is now the only download option from Office 365.

I use Acrobat Standard XI. Adobe told however that they have no timetable for making XI or DC compatible.

Does anyone know if it's possible to brute force patch my own PDFMaker driver plug-in? Or is there a secret nightly release candidate community that might be willing to share?

Comment: Are you using a consumer license? My enterprise license from work defaults to 2013, and lists 2016 as a beta version.

Comment: If a plug-in does not support a version of office, there isn't much you can do, except use a version of Office it does support.

Comment: no i'm using an enterprise version of office 365.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Outlook 2016 and the PDFMaker plugin. After enabling the Adobe PDFMaker Office COM Addin under COM Add-ins and restarting outlook it would complain about an error and uncheck the box.

To get around Adobe not officially supporting the Acrobat XI PDFMaker plugin on Office 2016 I performed the following registry (.reg) change. To use, just copy the below code to a new notepad document and save as .reg and change the 'Save As Type:' to All Files. Browse out to where you saved it and double-click on the .reg file to import the keys automagically. (Note: You need admin rights to make these changes. This was done on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. For a 32-bit machine or other Windows version this may not work. In that case, manually search for 'GreatestSuppVer' entries in the registry and change from 0000000f to 00000010.)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Office\SupportedVer]
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Outlook\SupportedVer]
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Office\SupportedVer]
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Outlook\SupportedVer]
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\Installer\X64Registry\PDFMaker\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Office\SupportedVer]
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\Installer\X64Registry\PDFMakerForOutlook\HKLM\Software\Adobe\Acrobat PDFMaker\11.0\Outlook\SupportedVer]
"GreatestSuppVer"=dword:00000010
"LowestSuppVer"=dword:0000000a
```